# LOAD Testing without correlation

Tags: jmeter

I am working for a startup. We need to Load test 500 requests for sec and 10,000 concurrent users at any given time.

We cannot afford loadrunner or any of these fancy softwares. We tried to implement it Jmeter. But it is unable to process this load.

Is there any cheaper software / online website, which can help with all the correlation issues and run the above load?

Comment: Loadrunner Community Edition is available for free [here.](https://saas.hp.com/buy/loadrunner)

Comment: JMeter can certainly support over 10,000 active threads when running in distributed mode.

Comment: The financial risk of it not working for 10,000 concurrent users dwarfs the cost of any tool or performance testing effort, from the most expensive commercial to the least expensive open source based practices.  Penny wise, dollar foolish

Comment: Correlation is a tool-user skill, not a tool skill

Comment: Also, its my experience that the commercial tools (LR, Silk, Neo) are not necessarily as effective with each load generator.  With careful JVM and Unix OS settings you can really get a lot of juice out of a single JMeter LG.

Comment: This is a test design issue.  I recommend at least three generators without regard to tool used on user based performance tests versus performance unit tests.  Reserve one of your hardware matched load generators for a control group.  Monitor during the test the performance of your control group versus your global group.  If your global performance degrades but your control group does not, then you have a test induced performance issue

Answer (score 0):

JMeter can support this load without any issue, ensure you follow best-practices:

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

If you don't have time to work on this, then select one of the available SAAS:

- http://redline13.com
- http://flood.io
- ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try our new service http://loadme.socialtalents.com

In case it is close to your needs but you need more threads please let me know

Answer (score 0):

[SmartMeter](https://www.smartmeter.io) supports [automatic correlations](https://www.smartmeter.io/documentation#toc-automatic-correlations) in the Light (free) version. It is based on JMeter, so in order to achive the desired load, follow @UBIK LOAD PACK tips.